# Iterate through different sheets in a HTML webpage

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm making a website to use as a social marketing app. The idea is to have a bunch of different sheets and iterate over them. Now I'm doing this making different html webpages and inserting a code like this in each one:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = "http://ip/nextpage"}, 5000);

</script>
```

I don't like this solution because I don't want to change from page to page (Chrome shows a little message with the redirection also). I think that would be better to have a single webpage that could show all sheets. How could I do this? Currently I'm only using HTML, Javascript and PHP but I wouldn't care to use other language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a js lightbox that will display pages in `<iframe>`s.

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/